# Can not debug my c++ program: error LNK2038: mismatch detected for

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, gmp

I just have installed `MPIR` library. I have tested that the program can see the header file in empty code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma warning(disable: 4800)
#include <mpirxx.h>
#pragma warning(default: 4800)

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   
  mpz_class aBigPO2;

  aBigPO2 = 1073741824; //2^30
  aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^60
  aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^120
  aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^240
  aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^480
  aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^960
  aBigPO2*=aBigPO2; //2^1920 
 // cout << aBigPO2 << endl;

cout<<"Hello World";
getch();
}
```

I tried to compile and debug the above code and it worked fine and I could see the Hello World statement. But, when I remove the comment in the `cout << aBigPO2 << endl;` statement, I get the following errors when I debug only (when I compile, it does not show any errors)

```
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\gcdgmp.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>mpirxx.lib(osmpz.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in Main.obj
1>mpirxx.lib(osdoprnti.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in Main.obj
1>mpirxx.lib(osfuns.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in Main.obj
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osdoprnti.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(__int64)" (?width@ios_base@std@@QAE_J_J@Z) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osfuns.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osdoprnti.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::rdbuf(void)const " (?rdbuf@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osdoprnti.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: char __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::fill(void)const " (?fill@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEDXZ) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osfuns.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall std::ios_base::flags(void)const " (?flags@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osdoprnti.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (?width@ios_base@std@@QBE_JXZ) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osfuns.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osdoprnti.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::tie(void)const " (?tie@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QBEPAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@2@XZ) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osdoprnti.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: bool __thiscall std::ios_base::good(void)const " (?good@ios_base@std@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osdoprnti.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ) already defined in mpirxx.lib(osdoprnti.obj)
1>c:\users\myuser\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\gcdgmp\Debug\gcdgmp.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.14
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What should I do ?

Comment: You've got the release build of that library, it is incompatible with your debug and CRT settings.  Build the debug version of that library from source.

Comment: Can you clarify more please with steps.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I did built the libraries using x64 and release settings. The same with my project that uses these libraries. My device is using Win x64 with Intel Xeon. My visual c++ is downloaded in Program Files  (x86). I built my project again and got: `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'mpir.lib'`. Is there any issue in this? How to solve it.

Comment: I could fix the latter error by right click on the project -> properties -> configuration properties -> C++ directories, then choose libraries directories and add navigate to the directory where the lib files are (mine: c:/mpir/win64/release).

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of a string literal is 16,384 (16K) bytes in CPP. Have you checked if (2^1920 = 9.49711451 x 10577) falls in this range?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in the #include for mpir.h and see if that fixes it.